# Security framework for Node.js web application

Tags: node.js, security, node.js-connect

My web application uses Connect middleware. 
I want to know if there are some security frameworks for Node.js web application, just like Spring Security or OWASP ESAPI?

Answer (score 1):

Try [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) very popular as well try [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) if you are looking for something lighter

Comment: passportjs is an authentication middleware, and it is cool!however, I need more security features, e.g.,input validation, output sanitization,CRSF token, session management, etc.

Comment: so you looking for nodejs framework that provides those features ? try [sailsjs](http://sailsjs.org/) its based on express not sure if thats what you are looking for